# Return Value from Method in Python using Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

So lets say i have this method in python

```
def get_data(notificaition):
    print("Notification Recived: ", notificaition)
```

And then i Have another method that recives a event and gets the value of that event.

```
def verify_singal_r():
    with Session() as session:
        connection = Connection("http://example/signalr", session)
        print(connection)
        logging.info("got the connection")
        presenceservice = connection.register_hub('MyHub')
        connection.start()
        def print_error(error):
            print('error: ', error)


        connection.error += print_error

        # TODO: NEED TO ADD POST REQUEST HERE
        presenceservice.client.on('Notified', get_data)
        connection.wait(10)
```

Once the Keyword `Verify_Signal` runs I get the values I need and i print them onto the console

How can I use the value of the `get_data` in robot framework?

I tried to simply use

```
*** Test Cases ***

Get Event Back
     verify_singal_r
     get_data
```

But that does not work as get_data expects an argument.

Answer (score 2):

your function

```
def get_data(notificaition):
    print("Notification Recived: ", notificaition)
```

Expects an argument

However when you are calling this in robot framework

```
*** Test Cases ***

Get Event Back
     verify_singal_r
     get_data
```

You are not providing any argument to it.

You can try  something like this

```
*** Variables ***
${notification}    Test
*** Test Cases ***

Get Event Back
     verify_singal_r
     get_data    ${notification}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I treid your example but I ma just getting `Notification Recived: ` how can i get the value that was generate in the python script?

Comment: Then in your python function you need to return something.

Comment: After a bit of debugging i found out that the `get data` is being called after the signal is verified which makes it ''empty'' , How can i get return value from the `verify signal r` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
def get_data(notificaition):
    print("Notification Recived: ", notificaition)
```

does not return anything, so robot framework keyword will not return anything too.